# How can one use GPT-4 to help authors iterate on LaTeX formatting?

Tags: formatting

I read in OpenAI's [GPT-4 Technical Report](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.08774.pdf):

> GPT-4 was used in the following ways: to help us iterate on LaTeX formatting [...]

How can one use GPT-4 to help authors iterate on LaTeX formatting?

---

Note that the training data of GPT 3.5 or 4 definitely included source code texts. [Example](https://chat.openai.com/share/d6c3208f-234a-4811-9cc5-eaf6367b3c1a) ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRAam.png)) --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBigy.png

Comment: It might be nice to mention that you asked the same question elsewhere (to minimize that people waste time). Also, the question seems more to be about GPT-4 than on LaTeX, so perhaps not on topic unless you clarify why it should.be.

Comment: @mickep [100% agreed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293150/178179) but I got downvoted and edited back a few times for mentioning that (wasn't on Tex.SE though but on other SE sites),  so I gave up. Instead, I gather any interesting info I may receive elsewhere back to SE. I agree it's suboptimal due to delays. I'm ok to move it to https://genai.stackexchange.com/ or http://academia.stackexchange.com/ but I thought it'd be the most on-topic here as the most important experience is latex.

Comment: Not aware is something essential changed in version 4 but I am afraid that there are not much to explain: (1) You demand something with human language. (2) Depending of how good you are explaining  the issue, the AI will show you some LaTeX code that presumably make what you asked and luckily what you want  really. (3) You must check/test the code to see if work as expected (4) Explain to the AI why the code is not working (5) Read  apologies and new code presumably correcting the mistakes (6)  Return to point 3 or 1 (sometimes the loop end in point 3.)

Comment: Not to sound overly cynical, but I have yet to see good, working TeX code come out of an AI, so, imho, the claim that one can use GPT-4 to help authors iterate on LaTeX formatting needs to be proven, still.

Comment: @Skillmon I thought I could trust OpenAI's claim on that. I don't see why they would advertise GPT-4 otherwise.

Comment: @Fran That's a bit disappointing. Maybe I should prompt about latex in some image GenAI system instead?

Comment: Afaik the issue is not very different with the AI images in general. You ask for dog and the AI make a picture that look like a dog only superficially, but  with five legs or some other artifact. Then, you try to refine the prompt again and again while the AI take odd decisions each time, but hopefully at the n-th attempt, the AI will make a picture that really seems a dog, although not exactly the dog that your are looking for.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I could also claim that my "ducksay" package improved productivity of researchers around the globe. A claim is close to worthless without something to back it up. And just amount of TeX related questions posed to an AI model is no metric to prove the given claim. As I said, I have yet to see good AI output in TeX.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt -- The value of an AI response depends on what was included in its training.  There's an overabundance of bad (La)TeX information on the net, so it's really hard to expect accurate/useful AI responses.

Comment: What does 'iterate' mean in this context? I'm assuming this is some programming term I'm not familiar with, but I've not seen the word used this way before and I'm having trouble figuring out what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to make definitive claims here, but anecdotally, I've had some success with Github Copilot (using GPT-3) generating large portions of TeX code following some pattern (structuring large equations, completing a set of similar macros, etc.). TeXGPT for Overleaf also looks like it could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can one use GPT-4 to help authors iterate on LaTeX formatting?

It can‘t in my view.

Though it‘s a language model, which may or may not have included source code texts, it has no knowledge, no sense of something being useful or useless, about beauty or ugliness etc. (and GPT had a time window, after which it had no data).

You can see this in the many examples mentioned in said report: results often remains on a toddlers level. And if you try generated code, it often doesn’t even compile, though the code looks tempting or interesting … sometimes. As one book author put it, „GPT has a tendency to hallucinate“. I.e. it fills something in many times. A layman may be impressed, while the expert can‘t stop raising his or her hair.

At the moment, and may be even for the next 70 years or so of hyping Artificial Incompetence, I‘d rather keep training my brain, on Latex, than trying to make a machine mimicking humans.

> How can one use GPT-4 to help authors iterate on LaTeX formatting?

At best as a programmer you can debug GPT-generated code, or use it a source of inspiration. But stay alert: the 4 quadrants still hold and are almost never evaluated in AI applications:

1. it appears to be right, and it‘s right
2. it appears to be right, but is wrong
3. it appears being wrong, but is right
4. it appears being wrong, and it‘s wrong

By no means can one know the average percentages for all 4 … and the two unwanted quadrants almost never come close enough to 0 %. See the examples in said report, e.g. about some simple math, see the face recognition errors (even 1 ppm error of being „detected“ as a terrorist while you aren‘t, isn‘t fun in cities with a couple of Millions inhabitants; BTW assuming 1 ppm is quite overoptimistic …), and so on.

Comment: Thanks! It definitely included source code texts. Example:  https://chat.openai.com/share/d6c3208f-234a-4811-9cc5-eaf6367b3c1a ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRAam.png)) --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBigy.png

Comment: Well ... if the prompt was "Give me an example of a fancy table in latex code." the outcome is a bit surprising, though not impossible. // It will become more interesting, once the prompt is varied. Enjoy the show : )

Comment: I mean gpt4 vision can actually see the output.. and iterate through that for what is worth.